# why winston moved from Logger to createLogger

Tags: winston

I was checking changes between winston 2.x and 3.x and got curious why

```
const logger = new (winston.Logger)...
```

was replaced with

```
const logger = winston.createLogger()...
```

was it only to hide default logger you get from `var winston = require('winston');` or I'm missing something else?

Comment: I can only assume the static method utilizes a config file to handle default instantiation arguments?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [factory pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Basically, you are able to create objects with more flexibility than a normal class instantiation using `new Class()`.

I **think** that's the reason behind this change, I'm not 100% sure though (didn't look at their codebase).

Comment: Thank you! that explained my scarce OO knowledge bit more.

Comment: @KarlisMelderis Sure, don't hesitate to upvote and accept answer if you find it useful :)